# plus 2 number == android studio

Tags: java, android

i am developing android simple calculator it works fine but only one issue when i press 2+3 and press = and again = and again = it should result 11 but not worked! my activity file is:

visit https://www.mediafire.com/edit/nit258ur24218e1/MainActivity.java

visit http://uplod.ir/n53dikr3y10w/MainActivity.java.htm

I can't add code 
error

please help me

```
` package com.example.administrator.mashinhesab;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button0, button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6,
            button7, button8, button9, buttonAdd, buttonSub, buttonDivision,
            buttonMul, buttonC, buttonEqual;

    EditText edt1;
    TextView edt2;

    private static final char ADDITION = '+';
    private static final char SUBTRACTION = '-';
    private static final char MULTIPLICATION = '*';
    private static final char DIVISION = '/';

    private char CURRENT_ACTION;

    private double num1 = Double.NaN;
    private double num2;
    private DecimalFormat decimalFormat;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViews();
        Button();
        decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##########");
    }
    private void Button(){
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edt1.setText(edt1.getText() + "1");
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edt1.setText(edt1.getText() + "2");
            }
        });

        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edt1.setText(edt1.getText() + "3");
            }
        });

        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edt1.setText(edt1.getText() + "4");
            }
        });

        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edt1.setText(edt1.getText() + "5");
            }
        });

        button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edt1.setText(edt1.getText() + "6");
            }
        });

        button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edt1.setText(edt1.getText() + "7");
            }
        });

        button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edt1.setText(edt1.getText() + "8");
            }
        });

        button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edt1.setText(edt1.getText() + "9");
            }
        });

        button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edt1.setText(edt1.getText() + "0");
            }
        });

        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                computeCalculation();
                CURRENT_ACTION = ADDITION;
                edt2.setText(decimalFormat.format(num1) + "+");
                edt1.setText(null);
            }
        });

        buttonSub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                computeCalculation();
                CURRENT_ACTION = SUBTRACTION;
                edt2.setText(decimalFormat.format(num1) + "-");
                edt1.setText(null);
            }
        });

        buttonMul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                computeCalculation();
                CURRENT_ACTION = MULTIPLICATION;
                edt2.setText(decimalFormat.format(num1) + "*");
                edt1.setText(null);
            }
        });

        buttonDivision.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                computeCalculation();
                CURRENT_ACTION = DIVISION;
                edt2.setText(decimalFormat.format(num1) + "/");
                edt1.setText(null);
            }
        });

        buttonEqual.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                computeCalculation();
                edt2.setText(edt2.getText().toString() + decimalFormat.format(num2) + " = "  + decimalFormat.format(num1));
                num1 = Double.NaN;
                CURRENT_ACTION = '0';
            }
        });


        buttonC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick(View v) {
                                           if(edt1.getText().length() > 0) {
                                               CharSequence currentText =edt1.getText();
                                               edt1.setText(currentText.subSequence(0, currentText.length()-1));
                                           }
                                           else {
                                               num1 = Double.NaN;
                                               num2 = Double.NaN;
                                               edt1.setText("");
                                               edt2.setText("");
                                           }
                                       }
                                   }
        );
    }
        private void computeCalculation () {
            if (!Double.isNaN(num1)) {
                num2 = Double.parseDouble(edt1.getText().toString());
                edt1.setText(null);

                if (CURRENT_ACTION == ADDITION)
                    num1 = this.num1 + num2;
                else if (CURRENT_ACTION == SUBTRACTION)
                    num1 = this.num1 - num2;
                else if (CURRENT_ACTION == MULTIPLICATION)
                    num1 = this.num1 * num2;
                else if (CURRENT_ACTION == DIVISION)
                    num1 = this.num1 / num2;
            } else {
                try {
                    num1 = Double.parseDouble(edt1.getText().toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
        private void findViews () {
            button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
            button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
            button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
            button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
            button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
            button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
            button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
            button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
            buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonadd);
            buttonSub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonsub);
            buttonMul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonmul);
            buttonDivision = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttondiv);
            buttonC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonC);
            buttonEqual = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoneql);
            edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt1);
            edt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edt2);
        }

}`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH2is.png)

I write 6+8=14 and again =write 148 and again =NaN8 and again = NaN

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please paste your codes here and don't link it to another website.

Comment: Hello , please post ur error log

Comment: I can't add code
error

Comment: Try to strip the code down to a smaller piece where the error occurs. It'll help future readers to reproduce the error without too much noise.

Comment: I write 6+8=14 and again =write 148 and again =NaN8 and again = NaN

Answer (score 0):

When you handle the equals press you set the `CURRENT_ACTION = '0';` so when you press it again none of the conditions are true.  What you want to achieve could work if you just remove that line.  I also recommend you look into some java and android reference materials so you can improve your code.

Comment: I add screenshot to first post
I write 6+8=14 and again =write 148 and again =NaN8 and again = NaN